# Route::auth Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes

Im learning laravel and i want to create a login/registration
module. For this i used the `php artisan make:auth` in the console. All good for the moment. But i do not want to use the `email-field` for login.

This is the `User::model`.

```
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    protected $table = 'login_usuarios';



    protected $fillable = [
        'rut', 'contrasena'
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

I want the user to use his RUT (Personal identification number) to access the system. But i keep recieving errors about emails.

I've searched in the imports `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` with no luck

Hope you understand. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in

```
app/Http/AuthController.php
```

try adding

```
protected $username = 'username';
```